# ASP.NET MVC HTML element alignment and width

Tags: html, css, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a question about aligning HTML elements on my ASP.NET Core MVC .cshtml page. I am trying to align two list boxes and their captions / labels side by side.

This is my .cshtml file:

```
<div style="width:100%;">
    <form method="post">
        <div id="div_top_hypers">
            <ul id="ul_top_hypers">
                <li>
                    <label align="left">List of Users</label>
                    </br>
                    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
                    {
                        @Html.ListBox("usersList")
                    }
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label align="left">List of Users2</label>
                    </br>
                    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
                    {

                        @Html.ListBox("usersList2")
                    }
                </li>
            </ul>
        <input type="submit" value="Generate reports" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="ScoreData"/>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

And my CSS section has the following content:

```
#div_top_hypers {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    display: inline;
}

#ul_top_hypers li {
    display: inline;
}
```

I need the two listboxes side by side... but I get them one below the other. How can I fix this?

Also, I am trying to make my listboxes wider. I used a div class with width set to, let's say, 200 pixels, but it does not reflect on the UI at all. It's always narrow.

At the moment, the width of the listbox is the width of the largest item inside it (I have not set it to auto, but if I set it to some width, it has no effect).

[image]

Comment: You can use float:left inside list.  <li style="float: left;">

Comment: I am now able to get them all aligned side by side... but the issue with the width of listbox remains...  

how can I define a standard width for each listbox item ? 

i have tried style="width : 100px;"  and it has no effect

Comment: `</br>` is not a valid tag. I assume you meant `<br />` or `<br>`.

Comment: Tieson, yes you are right. I have fixed it now. Thanks. Overlooked them when my eyes were on other issues.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change a few lines of your code as below:

```
<div style="width:100%;">
    <form method="post">
        <div id="div_top_hypers">
            <ul id="ul_top_hypers">
                <li>
                    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
                    {
                        @Html.Label("List of Users1")
                        @Html.ListBox("usersList1", usersList)
                        @Html.Label("List of Users2")
                        @Html.ListBox("usersList2", usersList2)
                    }
                </li>
            </ul>
            <input type="submit" value="Generate reports" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="ScoreData" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Use the above lines of code or the below lines. Both should work fine.

```
<div style="width:100%;">
    <form method="post">
        <div id="div_top_hypers">
            <ul id="ul_top_hypers">
                <li>
                    @Html.Label("List of Users1")
                    @Html.ListBox("usersList1", usersList)
                    @Html.Label("List of Users2")
                    @Html.ListBox("usersList2", usersList2)
                </li>
            </ul>
            <input type="submit" value="Generate reports" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="ScoreData" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

And keep the listbox height to 20 pixels. Then your output will look like below.

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRs0P.png)

Comment: Thank you.

I also tried this and it worked

                        @Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.selectedUsers, Model.ListofUsers, new { style = "width:200px" })

Answer (score -1):

if you are using bootstrap, because bootstrap is included with asp.net and MVC, in the ul you can add this

```cs
<ul class="d-flex justify-content-between ">
  <li class="w-25">
    stuff in here

  </li>
</ul>
```